# data cleaning with R language

Tags: r, database, data-cleaning

I have to build an access database from a txt file (that I obtained from a raw pdf file).
This in order to feed some stuff to a free quiz making software (quizfaber.com)
This is my input file:

```
001. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 2, art. 36, Reg. Ord. Penit., negli istituti penitenziari come sono disciplinate le modalità relative allo svolgimento dei vari servizi predisposti per i detenuti e per gli internati? 
A)Con singoli provvedimenti del direttore dell'istituto.
B)Con regolamento interno dell'istituto.
C)Con singoli atti del provveditore regionale competente.
002. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 7 , art. 47-quinquies, Ord. Penit., la detenzione domiciliare speciale può essere concessa anche al padre detenuto? 
A)Sì, alle stesse condizioni previste per la madre, in alternativa alla madre.
B)Sì, alle stesse condizioni previste per la madre, ma solo se la madre è deceduta e non vi è modo di affidare la prolead altri che al padre.
C)Sì, alle stesse condizioni previste per la madre, se la madre è deceduta o impossibilitata e non vi è modo di affidarela prole ad altri che al padre.
003. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 8-bis, art. 656, c.p.p. (Esecuzione delle pene detentive), quando il pubblico ministero può disporre la rinnovazione della notifica dell'avviso dell'ordine di esecuzione e del decreto di sospensione? 
A)Solo quando è sicuramente provato che il condannato non abbia avuto effettiva conoscenza dell'avviso.
B)In nessun caso.
C)Quando è provato o appare probabile che il condannato non abbia avuto effettiva conoscenza dell'avviso.
004. Quale sanzione disciplinare di cui all'art. 39, Ord. Penit., non può avere durata massima di quindici giorni? 
A)Isolamento durante la permanenza all'area aperta.
B)Esclusione dalle attività in comune.
C)Esclusione dalle attività ricreative e sportive.
005. In materia di "alimentazione" l'art. 9, Ord. Penit. dispone, tra l'altro, che: 
A)Il vitto è somministrato, di regola, in locali all'uopo destinati.
B)I prezzi di vendita devono essere almeno inferiori del 30% rispetto a quelli comunemente praticati nel luogo in cui èsito l'istituto.
C)Il servizio di vettovagliamento di regola non è gestito direttamente dall'amministrazione penitenziaria.
006. A norma del disposto di cui all'art. 76, Reg. Ord. Penit., quale ricompensa può essere concessa dal consiglio di disciplina, ai detenuti e agli internati, se ricorrano i presupposti? 
A)Encomio.
B)Nessuna delle altre risposte è corretta; tutte le ricompense sono concesse dal direttore dell'istituto penitenziario o dalmagistrato di sorveglianza.
C)Proposta di licenza.
007. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 11, art. 11, Ord. Penit., nel caso di diagnosi anche sospetta di malattia contagiosa devono essere messi in atto tutti gli interventi di controllo per evitare insorgenza di casi secondari, compreso l'isolamento; chi deve essere immediatamente informato? 
A)Il difensore della persona contagiata.B)Il famigliari della persona contagiata.C)Il direttore dell'istituto.
008. A norma del disposto di cui all'art. 40, Ord. Penit., quale tra le seguenti non è una sanzione disciplinare deliberata al consiglio di disciplina? 
A)Isolamento durante la permanenza all'area aperta.
B)Esclusione da attività in comune.
C)Richiamo.
009. In materia di "alimentazione" l'art. 9, Ord. Penit. dispone, tra l'altro, che: 
A)Una rappresentanza di soggetti non detenuti o internati controlla l'applicazione delle tabelle e la preparazione delvitto.
B)Tutti i detenuti hanno la stessa alimentazione; l'istituto non può tener conto di eventuali diverse richieste anche sepreviste dal credo religioso.
C)Il servizio di vettovagliamento è di regola gestito direttamente dall'amministrazione penitenziaria.
010. Al condannato ammesso al regime di semilibertà possono essere concesse a titolo di premio una o più licenze di durata non superiore nel complesso a 45 giorni l'anno. Chi provvede alla concessione? 
A) Il tribunale di sorveglianza. B) Il direttore dell'istituto penitenziario. C) Il magistrato di sorveglianza.
```

Here are the two requested output txt files

FIRST

```
1; 1; 1; 001. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 2, art. 36, Reg. Ord. Penit., negli istituti penitenziari come sono disciplinate le modalità relative allo svolgimento dei vari servizi predisposti per i detenuti e per gli internati?; Y 
2; 1; 1; 002. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 7 , art. 47-quinquies, Ord. Penit., la detenzione domiciliare speciale può essere concessa anche al padre detenuto?; Y 
3; 1; 1; 003. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 8-bis, art. 656, c.p.p. (Esecuzione delle pene detentive), quando il pubblico ministero può disporre la rinnovazione della notifica dell'avviso dell'ordine di esecuzione e del decreto di sospensione?; Y 
4; 1; 1; 004. Quale sanzione disciplinare di cui all'art. 39, Ord. Penit., non può avere durata massima di quindici giorni?; Y
5; 1; 1; 005. In materia di "alimentazione" l'art. 9, Ord. Penit. dispone, tra l'altro, che:; Y 
6; 1; 1; 006. A norma del disposto di cui all'art. 76, Reg. Ord. Penit., quale ricompensa può essere concessa dal consiglio di disciplina, ai detenuti e agli internati, se ricorrano i presupposti?; Y 
7; 1; 1; 007. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 11, art. 11, Ord. Penit., nel caso di diagnosi anche sospetta di malattia contagiosa devono essere messi in atto tutti gli interventi di controllo per evitare insorgenza di casi secondari, compreso l'isolamento; chi deve essere immediatamente informato?; Y 
8; 1; 1; 008. A norma del disposto di cui all'art. 40, Ord. Penit., quale tra le seguenti non è una sanzione disciplinare deliberata al consiglio di disciplina?; Y
9; 1; 1; 009. In materia di "alimentazione" l'art. 9, Ord. Penit. dispone, tra l'altro, che:; Y
10; 1; 1; 010. Al condannato ammesso al regime di semilibertà possono essere concesse a titolo di premio una o più licenze di durata non superiore nel complesso a 45 giorni l'anno. Chi provvede alla concessione?; Y
```

AND SECOND

```
1;A)Con singoli provvedimenti del direttore dell'istituto.; N; 1
1;B)Con regolamento interno dell'istituto.; N; 2
1;C)Con singoli atti del provveditore regionale competente.; N; 3
2;A)Sì, alle stesse condizioni previste per la madre, in alternativa alla madre.; N; 4
2;B)Sì, alle stesse condizioni previste per la madre, ma solo se la madre è deceduta e non vi è modo di affidare la prolead altri che al padre.; N; 5
2;C)Sì, alle stesse condizioni previste per la madre, se la madre è deceduta o impossibilitata e non vi è modo di affidarela prole ad altri che al padre.; N; 6
3;A)Solo quando è sicuramente provato che il condannato non abbia avuto effettiva conoscenza dell'avviso.; N; 7
3;B)In nessun caso.; N; 8
3;C)Quando è provato o appare probabile che il condannato non abbia avuto effettiva conoscenza dell'avviso.; N; 9
4;A)Isolamento durante la permanenza all'area aperta.; N; 10
4;B)Esclusione dalle attività in comune.; N; 11
4;C)Esclusione dalle attività ricreative e sportive.; N; 12
5;A)Il vitto è somministrato, di regola, in locali all'uopo destinati.; N; 13
5;B)I prezzi di vendita devono essere almeno inferiori del 30% rispetto a quelli comunemente praticati nel luogo in cui èsito l'istituto.; N; 14
5;C)Il servizio di vettovagliamento di regola non è gestito direttamente dall'amministrazione penitenziaria.; N; 15
6;A)Encomio.; N; 16
6;B)Nessuna delle altre risposte è corretta; tutte le ricompense sono concesse dal direttore dell'istituto penitenziario o dalmagistrato di sorveglianza.; N; 17
6;C)Proposta di licenza.; N; 18
7;A)Il difensore della persona contagiata.; N; 19
7;B)Il famigliari della persona contagiata.; N; 20
7;C)Il direttore dell'istituto.; N; 21
8;A)Isolamento durante la permanenza all'area aperta.; N; 22
8;B)Esclusione da attività in comune.; N; 23
8;C)Richiamo.; N; 24
9;A)Una rappresentanza di soggetti non detenuti o internati controlla l'applicazione delle tabelle e la preparazione delvitto.; N; 25
9;B)Tutti i detenuti hanno la stessa alimentazione; l'istituto non può tener conto di eventuali diverse richieste anche sepreviste dal credo religioso.; N; 26
9;C)Il servizio di vettovagliamento è di regola gestito direttamente dall'amministrazione penitenziaria.; N; 27
10;A) Il tribunale di sorveglianza.; N; 28
10;B) Il direttore dell'istituto penitenziario.; N; 29
10;C) Il magistrato di sorveglianza.; N; 30
```

In fact I have to create this two access tables, questions and answers

[image: questions]
[image: answers]

And then I'll set the relations as this-:

[image]

I don't know well how to start in R language to perform this task.

Firstable I should check if the input file contains any semicolon and trasform to something else (_ for example)

Second I should add all the stuff in order to represent all the fields of the table. The field values are fixed except for the indexes that are progressive

Third I should deal with the case when the three answers are placed on the same line.

I beg Your pardon for the long post and all Your suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: Tip - if you want to replace instances of ``;`` with ``_`` then look into using something like ``gsub(";", "_", data)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first output file is the questions list. Your second output file is the answers list. Simply put, your main objective is to separate the questions from the answers from your input file, and then add aesthetics to meet the desired output formats.

In the solution below, `output1` is the desired question information, and `output2` is the desired answer information. I added your stated goals in the commented code to kind of help show how each part is done.

```r
library(stringr) # used for string manipulations (required for `str_extract_all()` below)

# read input file
f <- readLines(file("input_file.txt", open = "r")) 

# Firstable I should check if the input file contains any semicolon and trasform[sic] to something else (_ for example)
f <- gsub(";", "_", f)

# Second I should add all the stuff in order to represent all the fields of the table. The field values are fixed except for the indexes that are progressive
f_questions <- f[grepl("^[0-9]", f)] # selects lines that start with a digit (because they are questions) 

output1 <- paste0(1:length(f_questions), "; 1; 1; ", f_questions, "; Y")


f_answers <- f[grepl("^[A-C]", f)] # selects lines that start with capital letters "A" through "C" (because they are answers)

# Third I should deal with the case when the three answers are placed on the same line.
f_answers <- unlist(str_extract_all(f_answers, ".\\)[^.]+.")) # makes one answer per string (assuming all answers contain and end with a period)

output2 <- paste0(rep(1:(length(f_answers)/3), each = 3), ";", f_answers, "; N; ", 1:length(f_answers))
```

```
> output1
 [1] "1; 1; 1; 001. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 2, art. 36, Reg. Ord. Penit., negli istituti penitenziari come sono disciplinate le modalità relative allo svolgimento dei vari servizi predisposti per i detenuti e per gli internati? ; Y"                                                                      
 [2] "2; 1; 1; 002. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 7 , art. 47-quinquies, Ord. Penit., la detenzione domiciliare speciale può essere concessa anche al padre detenuto? ; Y"                                                                                                                                          
 [3] "3; 1; 1; 003. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 8-bis, art. 656, c.p.p. (Esecuzione delle pene detentive), quando il pubblico ministero può disporre la rinnovazione della notifica dell'avviso dell'ordine di esecuzione e del decreto di sospensione? ; Y"                                                      
 [4] "4; 1; 1; 004. Quale sanzione disciplinare di cui all'art. 39, Ord. Penit., non può avere durata massima di quindici giorni? ; Y"                                                                                                                                                                                   
 [5] "5; 1; 1; 005. In materia di \"alimentazione\" l'art. 9, Ord. Penit. dispone, tra l'altro, che: ; Y"                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [6] "6; 1; 1; 006. A norma del disposto di cui all'art. 76, Reg. Ord. Penit., quale ricompensa può essere concessa dal consiglio di disciplina, ai detenuti e agli internati, se ricorrano i presupposti? ; Y"                                                                                                          
 [7] "7; 1; 1; 007. A norma del disposto di cui al co. 11, art. 11, Ord. Penit., nel caso di diagnosi anche sospetta di malattia contagiosa devono essere messi in atto tutti gli interventi di controllo per evitare insorgenza di casi secondari, compreso l'isolamento_ chi deve essere immediatamente informato? ; Y"
 [8] "8; 1; 1; 008. A norma del disposto di cui all'art. 40, Ord. Penit., quale tra le seguenti non è una sanzione disciplinare deliberata al consiglio di disciplina? ; Y"                                                                                                                                              
 [9] "9; 1; 1; 009. In materia di \"alimentazione\" l'art. 9, Ord. Penit. dispone, tra l'altro, che: ; Y"                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[10] "10; 1; 1; 010. Al condannato ammesso al regime di semilibertà possono essere concesse a titolo di premio una o più licenze di durata non superiore nel complesso a 45 giorni l'anno. Chi provvede alla concessione? ; Y"
```

```
> output2
 [1] "1;A)Con singoli provvedimenti del direttore dell'istituto.; N; 1"
 [2] "1;B)Con regolamento interno dell'istituto.; N; 2"
 [3] "1;C)Con singoli atti del provveditore regionale competente.; N; 3"
 [4] "2;A)Sì, alle stesse condizioni previste per la madre, in alternativa alla madre.; N; 4"
 [5] "2;B)Sì, alle stesse condizioni previste per la madre, ma solo se la madre è deceduta e non vi è modo di affidare la prolead altri che al padre.; N; 5"
 [6] "2;C)Sì, alle stesse condizioni previste per la madre, se la madre è deceduta o impossibilitata e non vi è modo di affidarela prole ad altri che al padre.; N; 6"
 [7] "3;A)Solo quando è sicuramente provato che il condannato non abbia avuto effettiva conoscenza dell'avviso.; N; 7"
 [8] "3;B)In nessun caso.; N; 8"
 [9] "3;C)Quando è provato o appare probabile che il condannato non abbia avuto effettiva conoscenza dell'avviso.; N; 9"
[10] "4;A)Isolamento durante la permanenza all'area aperta.; N; 10"
[11] "4;B)Esclusione dalle attività in comune.; N; 11"
[12] "4;C)Esclusione dalle attività ricreative e sportive.; N; 12"
[13] "5;A)Il vitto è somministrato, di regola, in locali all'uopo destinati.; N; 13"
[14] "5;B)I prezzi di vendita devono essere almeno inferiori del 30% rispetto a quelli comunemente praticati nel luogo in cui èsito l'istituto.; N; 14"
[15] "5;C)Il servizio di vettovagliamento di regola non è gestito direttamente dall'amministrazione penitenziaria.; N; 15"
[16] "6;A)Encomio.; N; 16"
[17] "6;B)Nessuna delle altre risposte è corretta_ tutte le ricompense sono concesse dal direttore dell'istituto penitenziario o dalmagistrato di sorveglianza.; N; 17"
[18] "6;C)Proposta di licenza.; N; 18"
[19] "7;A)Il difensore della persona contagiata.; N; 19"
[20] "7;B)Il famigliari della persona contagiata.; N; 20"
[21] "7;C)Il direttore dell'istituto.; N; 21"
[22] "8;A)Isolamento durante la permanenza all'area aperta.; N; 22"
[23] "8;B)Esclusione da attività in comune.; N; 23"
[24] "8;C)Richiamo.; N; 24"
[25] "9;A)Una rappresentanza di soggetti non detenuti o internati controlla l'applicazione delle tabelle e la preparazione delvitto.; N; 25"
[26] "9;B)Tutti i detenuti hanno la stessa alimentazione_ l'istituto non può tener conto di eventuali diverse richieste anche sepreviste dal credo religioso.; N; 26"
[27] "9;C)Il servizio di vettovagliamento è di regola gestito direttamente dall'amministrazione penitenziaria.; N; 27"
[28] "10;A) Il tribunale di sorveglianza.; N; 28"
[29] "10;B) Il direttore dell'istituto penitenziario. N; 29"
[30] "10;C) Il magistrato di sorveglianza.; N; 30"
```

**Diving into the code**

Most of these functions are base functions that are worth becoming familiar with. They are likely covered in R introduction courses.

The more complicated part in the code is the [regular expression](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html) used inside `str_extract_all()`, so I will explain that here.

`str_extract_all(f_answers, ".\\)[^.]+.")` extracts all occurrences of the regular expression pattern `".\\)[^.]+."` from the input strings `f_answers`.

- `".\\)[^.]+."` indicates that the pattern starts with a wild card character (expressed as `.`) followed by a closing parenthesis (expressed as `\\)`). The string can then match one or more of any character, *except* the period, until it reaches the period (`[^.]+.`). (FYI, the last part can also be coded as `[^\\.]+\\.` to prevent confusion of the period (`\\.`) with the wild card character.)

Comment: It works like a charm, tnx. I still have to solve some issues but they regard the quizfaber software import function